# Cannot bind source type Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel to model type Repower.Cms.Umbraco.Models.Test

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, model, controller, umbraco

First of all I am new to Umbraco so if you see some basic mistakes don't judge me.

So I am creating currently a Login form which he goes to the database (check Username and Password) and reads the value which he returns and let's him `Cannot bind source type Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel to model type Repower.Cms.Umbraco.Models.Test.`

This Is my HTML:

```
    @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<Repower.Cms.Umbraco.Models.Test>

@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}

<style type="text/css">
    .btnStyle {
        border: thin solid #000000;
        line-height: normal;
        width: 80px;
    }
</style>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "MembersProtectedPage", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="fontStyle">
        <center>
            <table style="margin-top: 100px;margin-left:150px">
                <tr style="height:30px">
                    <td align="right">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.User)
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:200px" align="right">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User)
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:250px;color:Red" align="left">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height:30px">
                    <td align="right">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:250px;color:Red" align="left">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height:30px">
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="btnStyle" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
    </div>
}
```

This is my Model:

```
    public class Test : RenderModel
{
    public Test() : this(new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current).TypedContent(UmbracoContext.Current.PageId)) { }
    public Test(IPublishedContent content, CultureInfo culture) : base(content, culture) { }
    public Test(IPublishedContent content) : base(content) { }

    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand sqlcomm;

    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public bool IsUserExist(string emailid, string password)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();

        sqlcomm = new SqlCommand();
        sqlcomm.Connection = conn;
        sqlcomm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcomm.CommandText = "dbo.uspLogin";
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pLoginName", User);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pPassword", Password);

        SqlParameter retval = sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@RESULT", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery(); // MISSING
        string retunvalue = (string)sqlcomm.Parameters["@RESULT"].Value;

        switch (retunvalue)
        {
            case "0":
                flag = true;
                break;
            case "1":
                flag = false;
                break;
            case "2":
                flag = false;
                break;
            default:
                flag = false;
                break;
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

And this is my Controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Login(Test model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (model.IsUserExist(model.User, model.Password))
        {
            ViewBag.UserName = model.User;
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(model.User, false);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or Password Incorrect.");
        }
    }
    return View(model);
   }
}
```

So I am inheriting a RenderModel because previously my error was "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type Repower.Cms.Umbraco.Models.Test', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel'."
So I changed it (searched a lot in the Internet) and now I get this error.

Is also the rest of the code correct? The way that I access the Database and everything? I am expecting a Return value from the Database (don't know if that is correct)

Could Someone please help me?
I need to get this done today.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues with your implementation.

## Use the Umbraco MemberService

You're reinventing the wheel by building a new table which holds member information (such as username and password).

Umbraco has built in membership which can handle members of your site. You can view the GUI in Umbraco at `/umbraco/#/member`. Using this GUI, you can manually create and edit members.

You can also programmatically create end edit members in this section using this `MemberService`.

For example, register a member:

```
var MemberService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService

var member = MemberService.CreateMemberWithIdentity(newEmail, newEmail, newName, "Member");

MemberService.Save(member);
MemberService.SavePassword(member, newPassword);

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(newEmail, true);
```

Login:

```
var memberService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService;

if (memberService.Exists(email))
{
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(email, password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, true);
    }
}
```

You can read about what other methods are available [here](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/management/services/memberservice).

## You're mixing up your MVC

Your `Test` model isn't purely a model, is also has some controller in it as it is handling database stuff too!

Ideally, your model should just contain the data which has been sent forward, and your `TestController` should handle using that data.

## As for fixing your binding issue

You're currently setting your page view model to `Repower.Cms.Umbraco.Models.Test`, where as I think it should be left as is.

Stop this model from inheriting from `RenderModel`.

Instead, render a partial with your code.

For your page view:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}
@Html.Partial("Login", new Repower.Cms.Umbraco.Models.Test())
```

Partial called `Login.cshtml`:

```
@model Repower.Cms.Umbraco.Models.Test
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<TestController>("Login"))
{
    <div class="fontStyle">
        <center>
            <table style="margin-top: 100px;margin-left:150px">
                <tr style="height:30px">
                    <td align="right">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.User)
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:200px" align="right">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User)
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:250px;color:Red" align="left">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height:30px">
                    <td align="right">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:250px;color:Red" align="left">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height:30px">
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="btnStyle" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
    </div>
}
```

Finally, update your controller to inherit from `SurfaceController`.

## I hope this helps

This isn't the complete solution but should help you get off on the right track.

Comment: Great! Thank you a lot, that worked! The thing is now on the Login it is giving me an error where it says `string retunvalue = (string)sqlcomm.Parameters["@RESULT"].Value;` The error is: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.'
Do you have any idea what it might be? Am I accessing the right way the Database?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The database is probably returning an integer of the number of rows that have been changed (so I'm guessing the integer `1`). You could use `sqlcomm.Parameters["@RESULT"].Value.ToString()` or better yet, not cast it to string: `int retunvalue = sqlcomm.Parameters["@RESULT"].Value`